# Increase size of ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.10.

I would like to use Gparted to resize the ext4 partition.  It is 81% full and

lately I have been getting warnings about the partition being full and to remove

files.

I am  little paranoid about doing this.  So, I have requested your careful instructions.

If there is a super safe way to do this I would like to do that.  All of the posts I have read

focus on using Gparted.

I have burned a Live CD of Gparted to unmount the ext4 partition which I understand is required in order to resize/ increase the size.

Here are the screenshots for review.  thank you for any help.

[Screenshot of Gparted information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt9mO.png)

Comment: The only safe way is to have good backups of both Windows & Linux. When hard drive fails you will need that anyway. Your / (root) was pretty small. I normally suggest 30GB when you have much larger /home or data partition for data. But you are not using much of Windows. Only use Windows tools to shrink Windows p3 and reboot to make sure it works. I might just do a new install in unallocated & copy /home into new install or separate /home partition. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: oldfred , unallocated has only 2.34 mb.  Will that increase/expand on a new install to allow for more space?  I am assuming I can set the size of the new install to unallocated.

Comment: You can't resize p7 (ext4) as there is p4 between the largest partition (p3) and p7 (ext4). If you want your Windows installation safe and sound I'd recommend shrinking p3 first then creating ext4 partition within the unused space left after shrinking. Imagine that gets label p8, you may keep p8 as root (/) for linux and p7 as /home. If this gives you some idea, decide on how much space you'd need in each partition. Then boot into Windows use disk management tool to shrink the volume. (Sometimes, you would need to defrag the disk before shrinking) then come back to LiveCD and do the rest.

Comment: You also cannot use gparted on your install, but only from live installer or gparted live flash drive. Your gparted screen shot shows the little key icon on your / (root) partition, so you used it from inside your install & it is mounted. Partitions must be unmounted to be modified.

Comment: I will be proceeding with this tomorrow.  W10 partition shrunk by 100gb.  Clonezilla image burned to disk for currently Ubuntu installation.  Next, I will use a Windows 10 disk imaging product I would recommend to anyone.  The Apricorn SATA Wire 3.0 kit for 25 dollars.  This is not a promotional pitch.  Memory on the drive in the kit has 1TB of storage space.  So, that is very good indeed.  Thanks for the feedback.